# keep values of image under certain dimensions in python

Tags: python, image-processing

Is there any pythonic way of doing exactly opposite of what I am showing in image below??

Image below is achieved using  `ang[1:int(h*.8),1: int(w*.8)]=0` where 'h' and 'w' are dimensions of image

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got a 2 liner solution for this, although I prefer one liner

```
 ang[:,int(w*.8):w]=0
 ang[int(h * .8):h,:] = 0
```

Comment: This is probably the best solution, I don't think a one-liner is something to aspire to. :)

Answer (score 0):

Would the following do the necessary ?

```
ang[int(h*.8)+1:,int(w*.8)+1:] = 0
```

Comment: Nope! I did the same thing but what I get was a small black box in the bottom right!!

Comment: So you need  2 black bands: one at the bottom and one at the right. Correct ?